# Using GetMethod and Invoke on a button click function

Tags: c#, invoke, buttonclick

I have the following code:

```
    object[] parameters = { new object(), new EventArgs() };
    Type[] type = new[] { typeof(object), typeof(EventArgs)};
    MethodInfo  theMethod = thisType.GetMethod("button_Click", type);

    object result = theMethod.Invoke(this, parameterList);
```

theMethod is null when I get to the theMethod.Invoke part. I don't understand why the function can't be found by GetMethod. It in the same partial class. This works for all my other functions.

Can I not use invoke on button clicks or are the parameter types special in some way? Is there another way to do this with button clicks?

Edit:

The button's function is:

```
private void buttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e) ...
```

Comment: What is `thisType`?

Comment: Also, please add the signature for `button_Click`

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. What are you trying to accomplish by invoking `button_Click`? You should move the implementation of `button_Click` to a `public` method. And, have `button_Click` and where you plan to use `MethodInfo.Invoke` to call the implementation method instead.

Comment: thisType was the forms type where the method was located.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't have the actual button's method as a public method, hence why I am doing it this way.

Comment: If you know the Button's name, you just call `[The Button].PerformClick();`. If you don't but you know the Event Handler (`buttonClick`):  `this.buttonClick(this, EventArgs.Empty);` or `this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => buttonClick(this, EventArgs.Empty)));` or `this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => buttonClick(this, EventArgs.Empty)));`

Comment: I clarified my answer regarding reflection. There probably _is_ a better way to solve your problem, but to answer that part of your question, we need to know what kind of application this is, i.e., which UI framework it uses. Is it WinForms?

Comment: Your function is `buttonClick`, but you give `"button_Click"`as Parameter to the `GetMethod()`. Maybe this underscore is what makes it not working.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your reflection approach doesn't work is that [Type.GetMethod(String, Type[])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethod?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Type_GetMethod_System_String_System_Type___) will only return public methods, and your `buttonClick` method is private.

To access non-public methods using reflection, you must use one of the overloads that accepts `BindingFlags` and include `BindingFlags.NonPublic` along with `BindingFlags.Instance` and/or `BindingFlags.Static`, depending on what you want to include in the search.

Very often, and especially when you're dealing with event handlers, there will only be method with the same name. In such cases, there's no need to specify the parameter types when calling GetMethod. Instead, you can use the simpler [GetMethod(String, BindingFlags)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethod?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Type_GetMethod_System_String_System_Reflection_BindingFlags_):

```
MethodInfo theMethod = thisType
    .GetMethod("buttonClick", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

#### Better ways to simulate a button click

In order to find the best approach to your problem, ask yourself the following questions:

**First:** Do you *really* need to use reflection? If you have control over the source code for the form that you're interacting with, i.e. with the possibility to add things in the form class, then you should skip the reflection stuff and add a public method for interacting with the button.

**Second:** Do you just want to *call a specific method* ("buttonClick", which also happens to be an event handler), or do you want to *properly simulate a user action* so that the UI framework becomes aware of the "click" and handles it (calling all attached event handlers, regardless of method names, etc)?

How to best simulate user actions depends on the framework you're interacting with:

- If the framework has a specific method for this, call that method (possibly via reflection, if you absolutely have to). WinForms buttons have the [PerformClick()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.button.performclick?view=netframework-4.7.2) method.
- Frameworks that don't have a separate method, like WebForms, usually have an OnClicked method that you can call. This might require the use of reflection, since these methods are often protected instead of public.

**Third:** If you're dealing with a Windows GUI framework (rather than a web framework), you may also need to make sure that UI manipulations initiated from your code are executed on the correct thread, otherwise you might get unexpected `InvalidOperationException` exceptions.

- **For WinForms:** If you're certain that your code will only be called through event handlers of other UI elements in the same application, then you shouldn't have to worry about threads.  Otherwise, you must wrap everything that may potentially manipulate the state of the UI (such as calls to `PerformClick()`) in a separate method and use [Invoke(Delegate)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=netframework-4.7.2) with that method. It's often easiest to use with a lambda expression, e.g. `formContainingButton.Invoke(() => button.PerformClick());`

(Other frameworks may have similar constructs for dealing with UI threads.)